What is the difference between flink watermarking and ksqlDB grace period?
I did some research on ksqlDB and Flink, it seems they are not compatible, and Flink becomes more popular. Could anyone give me some idea about the differences between flink watermarking and ksqlDB grace period? Thank you very much!
